# Using Symmetric keys in Tink

Tags: tink

I am trying to store cleartext password in properties file and load that JSON using CleartextKeysetHandle.read

However, when I want to rotate the key, I would like to introduce another key which is another cleartext password. How can I load this key and add it to keymanager ?

Answer (score 0):

Copied from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tink-users/5NHf8BOPWgM:

Yes. You can use KeysetManager [1] to rotate an existing keyset. Basically you read the keyset with CleartextKeysetHandle, and use the resulting KeysetHandle to build a KeysetManager which allows you to rotate, add or disable keys.

Cheers,
Thai.

[1] http://google.github.io/tink/javadoc/tink/1.2.2/com/google/crypto/tink/KeysetManager.html